# Block ability to create freestyle project in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

We have decided to finally get rid of freestyle jobs in our Jenkins.
Is it possible to prevent freestyle jobs from being created?

Answer (score 0):

Could try modify Daniel Beck's [hide-maven plugin](https://github.com/daniel-beck/hide-maven-plugin) to Hide Freestyle ?